# Scrollview - Can't scroll the dynamic content after load()

Tags: jquery, mobile, load, scroll, scrollview

**Header:**

```
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.easing.1.3"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.scrollview"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/scrollview"></script>
....! and the correct css !
```

**Body:**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div id="htmltext" data-scroll="y"></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

**In Pageshow event:**

```
$("#htmltext").load("content/test.htm", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});

$("#htmltext").scrollview("scrollTo", 0, -600);
```

After load(), can't scroll the dynamic div #htmltext!!!

Meanwhile, if I replace the load function by pure  code, it will be scrolled correctly.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem comes from the fact that Ajax works asynchronously. So in order to make anything **after** Ajax load, you should use its callback function. Try to move the scrolling method inside `load` handler function.

```
$("#htmltext").load("content/test.htm", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    $("#htmltext").scrollview("scrollTo", 0, -600);
});
```

Comment: I have tried with your code, but it's not work. Bind events to #htmltext also not work.

I have been used CSS functions, such as `code`transform(), transform3d(),... but they crop the content, not do scroll the content.

Comment: @TonyWu The code is workable. Check your `scrollview` function. Does it exist? I know `.scrollTop()` method and can't say anything about this one.

Comment: It looks work in theory, but in reality it doesn't work.

Nothing happen to trigger event after load:
`<a id="ctrl">Link</a>

// Load story content.
$('#htmltext').load("test.htm", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        console.error(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    $('#ctrl').trigger('click');
});

$('#ctrl').bind('click', function(event) {
    console.log("ctrl.click");
    $('#htmltext').scrollview("scrollTo", 0, -600);
});`

scrollview() belongs to jquery.mobile.scrollview.js